# Trying to make my navbar-brand a link to home page

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

It's not working I keep getting #top page any suggestions how to make my brand name home too

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url'home' %}">Bootstrap</a>


              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
            </li>
```

Comment: you question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "^$" as url pattern to your homepage view in urls.py and simply put href="/" into your html template

Comment: Thanks for your help sorry for taking so long to reply I was fixing other issues on the my website

Comment: Ok are you able to navigate? Did it solve your problem